# Writing to closed file descriptor doesn't raise error

Tags: c

In the following code:

```
int main(void) {
        printf("before child\n");

        int pid = fork();

        if(pid == 0)
        {
                exit(0);
        }
        int status;
        wait(&status);
        if(4 != printf("abc\n"))
                perror("printing to stdout\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Produces the output:

```
before child
abc
```

The call to exit() in the child should close all file discriptors, including stdout fd.
Then how can the parent process still write to stdout after it has been closed?

Comment: Checking the return value of printf but NOT checking it for `fork`, `wait` ???

Comment: Each process has its own descriptors. Closing in the child doesn't close the parent's descriptor.

Comment: You do realize the *parent* process will also emit `"abc"`?

Comment: @Barmar, The child and parent share the *same* file description for the stdout fd underneath, right? Meaning that if the child closes the stdout, the file of parent should be closed too?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, yeah, that's what my question is about: Since stdout is closed by the child, how is the same file still open in the parent?

Comment: No, that's not how it works. Each process has its own descriptor table, and the fd is an index into that table. When you fork, the child gets a copy of the descriptor table.

Comment: How could `fork` possibly work if it worked the way you seem to expect it to work? If one process terminated, closing all file descriptors, the other would lose I/O.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of file descriptors as pointers to reference-counted file objects.

When you `fork`, the child process gets new references to *the same* streams as the parent process. Both the parent and child's descriptors point to the same stream object.

When your child process `exit`s, all of the file descriptors of the child process are closed. But since the parent also has file descriptors to the stream objects, the streams don't go away.

Files and streams are only torn down once no one refers to them anymore. In this case, the parent process refers to them.

(For additional fun, check out the `dup` family of functions, which duplicate file descriptors in a similar way. With it, you can have, in a single process, two file descriptors for the same file.)

Comment: Formally, in the POSIX standard, there are 'open file descriptors' and 'open file descriptions'.  Each open file descriptor refers to a single open file description, but many open file descriptors may separately refer to a specific open file description (for example, after `dup()` or `dup2()`, there will be two open file descriptors referring to the same open file description; likewise after `fork()`.  'Tis fun...  The current position is a property of the open file description; the close-on-exec status is a property of the open file descriptor.  Care is required!